# Rails: undefined method `relationships_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was following the Michael Hart book and wanted to and add the follow and  unfollow button to the users show page. While implementing this I encountered this error `undefined method 'relationships_path'`.

Any help would be helpful and appreciated.

[image]

---

relationships controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

---

users controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

   before_action :authenticate_user!
   before_action :set_user



def create
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:followed_id])
  current_user.follow(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.js
  end
end

def destroy
  @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
  current_user.unfollow(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.js
  end
end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end
end
```

---

Relationship.rb

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

---

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId

    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower



      # Follows a user.
  def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  # Unfollows a user.
  def unfollow(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
  def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end

end
```

---

_follow.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @user.id %></div>                        
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

---

_unfollow.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id),
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>                       
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

---

show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="stats">
      <% @user ||= current_user %>

<div class="stats">

    <strong id="following" class="stat">
      <%= @user.following.count %>
    </strong>
    following
  </a>

    <strong id="followers" class="stat">
      <%= @user.followers.count %>
    </strong>
    followers
  </a>
      <%= render 'follow'  %>
</div>
    </section>
  </aside>

</div>
```

---

Routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

    get 'users/index'
    get 'users/show'

    devise_for :users do
        member do
          get :following, :followers
        end
    end

    get 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user

 end
```

---

Relationships | Migration

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id, index: true
      t.integer :followed_id, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post your routes file.

Comment: Can you show your `config/routes.rb` file content, problem lies in your routes

Comment: Can you post your routes file and `rake routes` output?

Comment: @Nermin and Pavan, I updated and added routes file at the bottom

Comment: Your route.rb don't have required route to `/relationships`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your route.rb, you don't have the required route i.e. POST `/relationships`. Add it into your `route.rb`:

```
resources :relationships
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks... I can't believe how I had forgot to add the resources